# tesseract ocr multipage pdf hangs

Tags: pdf, ocr, tesseract, multipage

We are using Tesseract's Java library, Called Tess4j to convert PDF files to text.
It works nicely with Tiff files as well as one page PDF files. But with multi-page PDF's it does generate the output file, when it comes to the last page, the control doesn't seem to come back to the original application which invoked the doOCR call. It just stays/hangs there without doing anything.
Is it an issue with the native call not returning back.i have no clue,

Please let me know if there is a solution to this issue, as soon as possible.

Regards
Vish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tess4J does support multi-page PDF and multi-page TIFF. Substitute with your PDF file in the unit test case and give it a try.